# Convert byte array signature of RSA algorithm to string and back to byte array again in .NET C#

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I am developing a .NET project. I doing encryption to some sensitive data. I am using RSA algorithm for it. I can successfully verify the hash message using private key, public key and signature.

But I am having a problem with converting byte array signature generated by RSA algorithm to string and convert that string back to byte array for verification. But verification fails if I verify signature with byte array that is converted back from signature string. My scenario is below.

This is my complete Cryptography class with RSA algorithm

```
public class Cryptograph:ICryptograph
    {
        private string RsaHashAlgorithm { get; set; }

        public Cryptograph()
        {
            this.RsaHashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
        }

        public RSAParameters[] GenarateRSAKeyPairs()
        {
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                RSAParameters publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
                RSAParameters privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
                return new RSAParameters[]{ privateKey , publicKey };
            }
        }

        public byte[] SignRsaHashData(RSAParameters privateKey,byte[]hashOfDataToSign)
        {
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
            {
                rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);

                var rsaFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);
                rsaFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm(RsaHashAlgorithm);

                return rsaFormatter.CreateSignature(hashOfDataToSign);
            }
        }

        public bool VerifyRsaSignature(RSAParameters publicKey,byte[]hashOfDataToSign, byte[] signature)
        {
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);

                var rsaDeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(rsa);
                rsaDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm(RsaHashAlgorithm);

                return rsaDeformatter.VerifySignature(hashOfDataToSign, signature);
            }
        }

    }
```

I test verification. Below is the working code and successfully verified

```
[TestMethod]
        public void VerifyRsaEncryptionSign()
        {
            var document = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test message");
            byte[] hashedDocument;
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                hashedDocument = sha256.ComputeHash(document);
            }

            Cryptograph crypto = new Cryptograph();
            RSAParameters[] keys = crypto.GenarateRSAKeyPairs();
            RSAParameters privateKey = keys[0];
            RSAParameters publicKey = keys[1];

            byte[] signature = crypto.SignRsaHashData(privateKey, hashedDocument);       
            bool verified = crypto.VerifyRsaSignature(publicKey, hashedDocument, signature);
            Assert.IsTrue(verified);
        }
```

Above code, unit test passed and successfully verified.

But what I want is I want to convert the signature byte array and convert that string to byte array back for verification like below code.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void VerifyRsaEncryptionSign()
        {
            var document = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test message");
            byte[] hashedDocument;
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                hashedDocument = sha256.ComputeHash(document);
            }

            Cryptograph crypto = new Cryptograph();
            RSAParameters[] keys = crypto.GenarateRSAKeyPairs();
            RSAParameters privateKey = keys[0];
            RSAParameters publicKey = keys[1];

            byte[] signature = crypto.SignRsaHashData(privateKey, hashedDocument);
            string stringSignature = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(signature);// Converted byte array to string
            signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringSignature);//convert string back to byte array
            bool verified = crypto.VerifyRsaSignature(publicKey, hashedDocument, signature);
            Assert.IsTrue(verified);
        }
```

When I run unit test, verification fails. What is wrong with my code? How can I successfully convert it? I would like to ask additional question as well. Is it possible to convert to hashed message back to original string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use base 64. Signatures consist of random bytes; not all random bytes do however represent a valid character when decoded.

Basically you should only decode strings that were previously *encoded*.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the hashed message back to original string with my code please?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you are trying to do. Please be as precise as possible.

Comment: Now, I am hashing the message. Then sign the message using private key. Then I just verify using sign and public key. But how can I decrypt the hashed value back to get original message? Actually what I am doing with my application is encrypt the message with private key. Then receiver will decrypt the message using public key. Signature will be sent along as well. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You cannot, hashes are one way. Encryption should be performed using the public key of the receiver. If you require less space for the signature use ECDSA.

Comment: Thanks so much for support.